# Pin Links to the Left-Hand Rail in Microsoft Teams

Tags: hyperlink, navigation, microsoft-teams

I need to pin important links of SharePoint to the Left-Hand Rail in Microsoft Teams

Please check attached image for better understanding.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxemX.png) to open the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left rail is only for actual Teams apps, so you can't pin just a web link there directly. However, there are a few options:

1. Develop a custom "tab" app that you deploy into a local company store. See this tool (built into Teams from Microsoft) to try out creating an app like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/app-studio-overview
2. Use Viva Connections, which provides it's own rail (but you need an entire SharePoint intranet site for this
3. Use a third party app like [Quicklinks](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200001833) which lets you add your own "bookmarks" app in the left rail, for multiple web links.